# Axios vs Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios

I am doing a post request to an [URL](https://www.localgov.ie/en/views/ajax) with some formdata.... I am interested in capturing the ***"command":"insert"*** part which is in the response..

when I make a post to an url using [AXIOS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). I dont get this ***"command":"insert"*** part

```
axios.post('https://www.localgov.ie/en/views/ajax', {  
  validation_date_from: "10/10/2017",       
  view_name : "bcsm_search_results",
  view_display_id : "notice_search_pane",
  view_path : "bcms/search"
}).then(function(response){    
  console.log( response.data)
  console.log("--------------------------------AXIOS POST")
})
```

*but* when I make a call to the same [URL](https://www.localgov.ie/en/views/ajax) using the same form variables BUT using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).
 I get the  ***"command":"insert"*** part

```
 var formdata ={
    validation_date_from: "10/10/2017",       
    view_name : "bcsm_search_results",
    view_display_id : "notice_search_pane",
    view_path : "bcms/search"
  } ;

    request.post({
      url: 'https://www.localgov.ie/en/views/ajax',
      form: formdata
  },
  function (err, httpResponse, body) {
      console.log(body);       
    console.log("--------------------------------request POST")
  });
```

[Here is a demo I have put on RequireBin](http://requirebin.com/?gist=164eba96741a851f99cfb96cd2a562e2).. Kindly run on mozilla or Cors disabled Chrome.

Comment: http://requirebin.com/?gist=164eba96741a851f99cfb96cd2a562e2 broken link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with **axios**' handling of POST requests with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. [There is an open issue that offers some discussion and possible workarounds in **axios**' GitHub page](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362).

Comment: so does that means that I should stop using axios for posts & rather go for request  ??? :o

Comment: No, you should always use axios, its more efficient, by you have to set the request header-field to `Content-type: application/json`.

Comment: Is that an objective answer @AyonLee? Why is axios more efficient?

Comment: @ZachSmith Axios is 98% smaller than request in package size, see here for Axios: https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=axios@0.21.0 and here for request: https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=request@2.88.2.