# Node.js request working with "request" module but not with "axios"

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to make a request with axios to the server. The problem is that my request works fine with the request module but not with axios. My code looks loke this:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.post('https://mydomain/api/login', {
  username: 'test@gmail.com', 
  password: '123'
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The answer from the server is:

```
{ response: 'Error', error_message: 'Invalid credentials' }
```

I make the same request with the same credentials but with the request module and it works just fine.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { 

  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://mydomain/api/login',
  formData: { username: 'test@gmail.com', 
              password: '123' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

The response from the server is :

```
{"response": "Successfully authenticated.", "email": "test@gmail.com",}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: do you use `https:mydomain/api/login` or `https://mydomain/api/login` ?

Comment: Axios sends JSON by default, not form data, see e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair I am using https:// .I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
const axios = require('axios');
var querystring = require('querystring');
axios.post('https://mydomain/api/login', querystring.stringify({username: 'test@gmail.com', password: '123' }))
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your request header for `Content-Type`.

You may need to set your axios configuration for POST request header `Content-Type`. This means the header should be:

`Content-Type: application/json`.

This is a known issue with Axios as explained in this post:
[Axios vs Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749408/axios-vs-request)

Comment: I tried with  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json',}
It's the same response "Invalid credentials"

Answer (score 0):

you are sending the credit in the body with the axios

```js
axios.post('https:mydomain/api/login', {
  username: 'test@gmail.com', 
  password: '123'
})
```

but with the request module you are sending it with the formData:

```js
var options = { 

  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https:mydomain/api/login',
  formData: { username: 'test@gmail.com', 
              password: '123' } };
```

Comment: Any idea how should I do it with Axios?

Comment: try to set the headers with headers `Content-Type:'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: and Axios should handle this for you